# Does anyone have experience with BSODs while creating a universal image with FOG?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I want to create a Windows XP universal image to image our computers using FOG server. The FOG server part is running fine, however when creating a Windows XP universal image, it keeps crashing (BSOD) with the 0x000007b error.

I believe this has todo with the Mass Storage drivers, I followed **many** tutorials, but each of them crashes with the 0x000007b error. FYI, I followed [this tutorial](http://fogproject.org/forum/threads/how-to-create-a-universal-windows-xp-image-using-mysysprep-exe-and-vm-ware.616/) (but couldn't download the files, the host is down).

I was wondering if any of you had experience with this and knows how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by setting the hard drives into `IDE` (legacy mode) through the BIOS.